# Python Breaking While Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, break

I am trying to break out of a while loop in Python 3

```py
while not at_end()...:
    if ...:
    else:
    code here
    if at_end():
        break
```

However, this does not seem to break the while loop. I have also tried putting the if right after while loop, but it does not work either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `at_end()` evaluate? The `while` loop will exit once it evaluates to `False`. There is no need to have the `if-statement` at the end of your code

Comment: Well, are you sure the `at_end()` function is working correctly? try doing `if True: break` instead to check if the problem is the function definition

Comment: nvm thanks guys. I fixed it. I forgot that I had the function containing while loop within forloop

Comment: I don't think the break statement is the issue. It should break out of the loop in that format. The problem likely is due to your at_end() function not evaluating correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should've been done in a for loop.
But if it needs to be a while loop you can do something like this.

```
while_flag = True
while while_flag:
    if:
        something
    else:
        something else
    if at_end():
        while_flag = False
```

Comment: Maybe it's a matter of personal preference, but I find more readable `while not stop_flag:` and `stop_flag = True`.

Answer (score 0):

You would typically do it like:

```
not_at_end = True
i = 0

while not_at_end:
    if i < 3:
        print('do stuff')
        i += 1
    else:
        print('do other stuff')
        not_at_end = False

# do stuff
# do stuff
# do stuff
# do other stuff
```

The iterator (i) is just to show example code. The main point is to use a boolean to break the while loop.